# How can I make a code cell in Jupyter Notebooks display a LaTeX with a package (via \usepackage{})?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex

I'm writing a package that works with constituency trees - as in syntax trees in Context Free Grammar, (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KXm6.png)). I've written code that generates the correct LaTeX expression to display the tree using `qtree`, e.g.:

```
\Tree [.S [.NP [.PN she ] ] [.VP [.V saw ] [.NP [.NP [.Det the ] [.N dog ] ] [.PP [.Prep with ] [.NP [.Det the ] [.N telescope ] ] ] ] ] ]
```

I'm using a Jupyter Notebook for some testing and demonstration, and I know that `IPython.display` is able to display LaTeX in the output of a code cell - but I don't know how to incorporate `\usepackage{qtree}` into the LaTeX so the tree will display. Is this possible, and if so, how?